# Will updating KDE also update Qt?

Tags: kde, opensuse, qt

Right now I'm using OpenSUSE 12.2 with KDE 4.9.4. If I upgrade that to KDE 4.10 in January, will it also bring in Qt 5 (or at least newer Qt packages)? Or are the Qt packages tied to the OS?

Comment: KDE 4.10 does not require `QT5` and it needs Qt (>= 4.7) and kdelibs (4.8) development packages.so mostly it won't be updated and `KDE5` will be using `QT5` it seems.

Comment: @harish.venkat OK, thank you. That answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a little detail: OpenSUSE 12.2 is using libQt 4.8.1, while Tumbleweed and Factory (12.3) are using libQt 4.8.4. There will be no need to perform a major version upgrade to Qt5 in the foreseeable future. Equally, as harish provided; KDE4.10 does not require Qt5; so if you *are* running an installation of openSUSE Factory (which will receive Qt5 first) - you can hold back the packages by using Zypper's [lock commands](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB%3aZypper_usage#Package_locks).